# If I am checked by ticket inspectors on the bus in Oslo with a ticket that expired over 1 hour ago, how to prove my ticket is actually valid?

Tags: transit, tickets, public-transport, norway, oslo

There is this rule in Oslo public transport that has me wondering. I am gonna get to the more extreme example in the title of the question near the end, but I will start with an actual example that happened to me today:

Today, I took the metro from the Jernbanetorget to Ullevål Stadion for a quick errand, and got a single use ticket for the trip. This ticket lasts for 60 minutes.

When my errand was done and I was about to hop on the metro for my 15 minute trip back home to Tøyen, I noticed that I still had 5 minutes left on my ticket from earlier. So my ticket would be valid for the first 5 minutes of my trip, but for the last 10 minutes of my trip, my ticket app would say that I had no valid ticket.

[According to Ruter:](https://ruter.no/en/buying-tickets/tickets-and-fares/single-tickets/)

> You may transfer to other means of transport (free transfer) in those
> zones for which the ticket applies, as long as the ticket remains
> valid **when you get onboard.**

Emphasis mine.

I reasoned that my stop at Ullevål Stadion can be considered a free transfer, and that the ticket is considered valid for the entire trip home to Tøyen as well, as long as the ticket is valid *at the time of boarding*.

It only makes sense that a ticket is valid for an entire leg as long as it is valid at the time of boarding. There are many trips inside Zone 1 for which the fastest route takes longer than 1 hour (such as going from Bjørndal to Voksen Skog). If you could not go on such a journey on a single Zone 1 ticket of 60 minutes, but would have to purchase multiple tickets for a single trip just because the buses are slow, that would be rather unreasonable.

This makes me wonder, though, because there is no way to prove what sort of trip you have been on. (The ticket app does not collect location data, and there are also "offline" travel cards).

As an extreme example, I could have taken the bus or metro from somewhere else in Groruddalen to Grorud, then, with 2 minutes left on my ticket, boarded [the 31 bus to Snarøya](https://moovitapp.com/index/nb/kollektivtransport-line-31-Norway-1679-1102884-683085-0). Over an hour and nearly 40 stops later, when I am nearly at Snarøya, my ticket should (even though it technically expired over an hour ago), be valid, since it was valid when i boarded the bus.

However, if I am stopped by ticket inspectors, I can not prove this. I might be a travel enthusiast who likes going around Oslo for the views. However, to ticket inspectors it might seem like an unlikely scenario that I boarded the 31 bus with a ticket with only 2 minutes left on it, over an hour ago.

One solution I have thought about is to let the driver know when I am boarding the bus, so that he can vouch for me in case the inspectors do not believe me. However, what about the metro, where one can not talk to the driver?

Comment: This is a rant, not a question; if you feel this is unjust, take it up with transit authorities in Oslo.

Comment: I assume that the answer is not more spectacular, than that the ticket inspector must prove that you entered whatever you are currently travelling on with an invalid ticket and not the other way around that you have to prove that you have been long enough aboard.

Comment: If only a few minutes are left on your ticket, you 'should' buy a new ticket and safe yourself the worry. It might be legal to milk out the last of the travel out of a ticket, but it is likely bending the rules if not really breaking them.

Comment: A **single use** ticket that can be used **twice** with a stop-off in between makes no sense to me. Is the 60 minute validity the period during which *the single journey* you’ve paid for can be made? On my local public transport, single use tickets are valid for 4 minutes once activated. You have to board the bus within 4 minutes, but your journey can last a lot longer providing you stay on the *same* bus.

Comment: @Traveller The ticket system has no way of knowing which bus or metro you're on. All it cares about is time and zones. You don't stamp it to let the system know that you're getting on and off the bus.

Comment: I know nothing about the Oslo transit system, but: what kind of ticket is it? Paper, magnetic, smart card, phone-based? Is there any validation when you board the bus or enter the metro system? In many places, validation is mandatory on each transfer, so (a) the system can check your ticket is still valid and (b) there is a record somewhere that you entered that specific bus with a valid ticket. How does validity start (and end) if there's no stamping or validation of any form?

Comment: @jcaron They offer this NFC card and smartphone app, two options. No, there is no validation when you board. You only activate your ticked once, before boarding the train or bus. There is no way to "register" a transfer.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a modern transport ticketing system that keeps *no record* of the stations you enter and exit? Don't you tap your phone on a console to enter a platform, or a bus? The app might not keep a record, but surely the transport system does?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am definitely saying that. The transport system can not keep record, because it has no way of knowing which travelers are on which buses and are traveling where. The ticket app does not need location access to work, and only uses it (optionally) to help people buy tickets for the right zone. You can very well just deny location access to the app, buy your ticket for the correct zone, and be on your way. Similarly, you can get an NFC travel card, activate it on a random station, and then be on your way, without letting it interact with the transport system at all after that.

Comment: In UK, you have to pass a barrier to access a train, that ensures you have a valid ticket. You pass the ticket through a slot, or tap the phone on a NF sensor. It doesn't need the phone's location, because it knows where the sensor/reader is. On a bus, you tap your bus pass on a panel, and so on. They know which bus you are on without location access of your phone.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, there is no such system in Oslo. You do not need to stamp or validate anywhere (apart from the act of activating your ticket before use). The only reason for having a ticket (apart from ethics and morals) is that you risk being checked by inspectors and fined if you do not have one. Oslo did try to implement a UK-like system years ago (and spent loads of money setting up gates and checkpoints), but later abandoned the idea.

Comment: @Willeke If you use the ticket app or the NFC based travel card in Oslo, you can't buy a new ticket before the previous ticket has expired. The app won't let you buy one and if you use the NFC card on a ticket vending machine, the vending machine will simply tell you that you don't need a new ticket, since you already have a ticket on the travel card valid for the new trip.

Comment: London rules: Once you use your ticket on a bus, you can stay on the bus as long as you like, and get onto other buses for sixty minutes. The record is someone managing to get on 24 buses. That required some excellent planning.

Comment: Think this is a really interesting question rather than a rant; will make an effort to answer it based on personal experience in similar situations.

Comment: @Traveller This type of fare is designed to make it the same price to get to your destination whether it is served by a direct bus or requires a change. The thinking is that for most 2 (or even 3) bus journeys from a to b, you'll have boarded your final bus within an hour. For most return journeys, you are unlikely to have been able to complete your errand & start the journey home within an hour of boarding the first bus. It's not intended for return journeys, but if a small percentage of customers are able to use it for a return journey then it doesn't bother the transport company that much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have spent two summers as a ticket inspector in Oslo, so this is the "correct" answer for Oslo.

In our (brief) training, we were taught that if someone claims they entered the bus with a valid ticket and this is possible according to the timetable then we should not fine them, however unlikely the scenario.

If the ticket inspector gives you a fine anyway then you can complain online and you won't have to pay it. You must of course show that what you claim is possible.

Comment: But the usage of single-ticket is to go on the shortest path from A to B, not to run errands in between, right?

Comment: The ticket remains valid for a duration of 60 minutes within a single zone. During this time, you are allowed to make multiple transfers between different buses or trams. To ensure your transfers are valid, make sure you board the last bus or tram before the expiration of your ticket. 
Note: if your ticket's validity ends at 10:01 and you decide to board a bus scheduled for departure at 10:02, but the bus unexpectedly arrives early at 10:00, you could face a fine. This is because your ticket would have expired prior to the scheduled departure, and the inspector will only check the timetable.

Answer (score 11):

The tl;dr answer — based on personal experience with similar situations — is at the time you board the bus, *take a screenshot of the app* if you only have your phone, or even better, *take a photo of your mobile with the app activated* with some kind of bus identifier in the background, or at least the farebox, should you also have a camera with you (as you might when you are sightseeing).

As a longer answer, in practice, in more casual cultures, a fare inspector probably will listen to what you say, look at their watch, nod, and move on, especially if you clearly are a local. In most places, a long suburban route is unlikely to have fare inspectors because ridership is not high enough to cover the cost of enforcement, either.

However, depending on the culture and the severity of a potential penalty — particularly if you do not speak the local language well or at all — it really isn't that paranoid to document your entry accordingly. If it is an option, you might also just choose to buy a new ticket if you're cutting it close. Transit commonly is underfunded as is.

As a couple of real-world examples:

1. In Vancouver, Canada, before TransLink put in turnstiles on the
   train, fare inspections were conducted by police and reportedly
   those without a ticket or with an expired ticket actually could be
   *charged with an offence and compelled to attend court*. Vancouver has turnstiles now, thankfully. However, if you are in
   a city where the penalties potentially are so severe and time consuming, a screenshot or a photo
   definitely is worth the effort!
2. In Paris, France, I once just purchased a Navigo monthly pass from a
   local shop. You are required to then take a photo of yourself using a vending
   machine in the metro and manually affix this physical photo to your card. The photo machine
   was broken in the nearest metro station, so I used my phone to take a photo of
   the metro card and the receipt in front of the broken machine with
   its "out of order" screen visible. Figuring that the odds of getting
   hassled by a fare inspector on a single trip were unlikely regardless, I went on the train with
   the plan to use the photo machine at the arrival station.

   Paris, of course, is notorious both for locals jumping turnstiles
   without payment and for fare inspectors that enforce aggressively at
   stations with heavy tourist traffic. Despite the single trip, I was intercepted by fare enforcement in a tunnel at the
   arrival station, but because I had the documentation, I was permitted to go upstairs to use the photo machine in that
   station without penalty. Had I not taken a photo of the broken machine at the departure station, it likely
   would have been an expensive and unpleasant encounter.

Ultimately, a little bit of documentation always is a good idea, particularly if you think there might be the possibility of a dispute. Safe travels!

Comment: Good suggestion. But FWIW, simple fare evasion isn't a crime in Canada, it is a municipal or provincial offence, similar to a speeding or even a parking ticket; but unlike some other countries, police officers or peace officers in general have no power to fine you, that is, to compel you to pay a certain amount of money; only a court can do so if it finds you guilty of a violation of law. Appearance in a court is for the protection of your rights and you can waive it by admitting to the offence (pleading guilty) and pay the ticket.

Comment: @xngtng Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the applicable sentence to say charged with an "offence" and "compelled" to attend court. Is this more legally accurate?

This answer wasn't intended to be legal advice. The point generally is that in some places, if there were a dispute, you might just have to pay a small "penalty fare" on site and move on with your life. Dealing with a courtroom is an enormous hassle by the standards of many cultures.

Comment: "especially if you clearly are a local": in my experience, most recently in Geneva, ticket inspectors are more likely to be forgiving if you are _not_ a local.